# Why is this repeating? [PYTHON]

Tags: python

Hey I been making a match finder in python and I came across this error it loops the print function and not go on. Here is my code:

```
string = "Hello"
letter = 0
while letter < len(string):
    if string[letter].lower() == string[letter + 1].lower() or string[letter].lower() == string[letter - 1].lower():
        print("Found a match of " + string[letter])
        exit()
    else:
        print(string[letter], end='\n')
        letter += 1
```

Comment: Oh and by the way if I remove the "exit()" function it makes the loop.

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking about or what problem you're facing

Comment: @Sayse I'm saying if I use this string `string = "Hello, I'm programming."` The matches are "l" and "m" I want it to output `Found a match of l` and `Found a match of m` here is  my refurbished code because I realized I didn't need the other `or` in the `if` function.
`string = "Hello, I'm programming."
letter = 0
while letter < len(string):
    if string[letter].lower() == string[letter + 1].lower():
        print("Found a match of " + string[letter])
    else:
        print(string[letter], end='\n')
        letter += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed it to a for loop, and it now works as per requested.

Code:

```
string = "Hello, I'm programming."
for index, letter in enumerate(string):
    condition1, condition2 = False, False
    if index < len(string)-1:
        condition1 = string[index].lower() == string[index + 1].lower()
    if index > 0:
        condition2 = string[index].lower() == string[index - 1].lower()
    if condition1 or condition2:
        print("Found a match of " + letter)
    else:
        print(letter)
```

Comment: If I use a string like `string = "Hello, I'm programming."` The matchs being "l" and "m" it will only output one match. @KetZoomer

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know how to make it match with the same letter behind or front.

Comment: @Sago I fixed that, also, can you click the checkmark to accept my answer as the correct one

Comment: There, and Thanks!